# Abort a table import stuck in 'pending'

Tags: google-bigquery

Similar questions have been asked but not exactly what I am looking for.

The problem: on some occasions importing a table from Google Cloud to Big Query gets stuck in a 'pending' state for hours if not days. Tables that get stuck in this state never seem to come out of it, or at least we didn't bother waiting that long. I know it's not a queue issue since in the mean time we can import other tables just fine. No errors are returned by Big Query.

My question: in this situation, and in general, how can we safely abort/cancel an import to Big Query without having the table quietly import on us without us knowing. This would actually apply to any table regardless of its state, as long as it hasn't finished importing.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example job id of an import that was stuck in pending for a long time while other imports were succeeding?

Comment: We currently don't have such a job id, but this happens around once every couple of weeks or so. Each time we used the web API Explorer provided at: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/get
and we confirmed the status was stuck on 'pending', while we were able to import other tables.

Comment: If you see this again, can you capture the job id from the jobs.list?

Comment: Sure, next time we will.

Comment: @JordanTigani we have a number of tables currently stuck in "Pending", can you please let us now what the problem is. Here are some of the job ids:


job_uotCPAngqGdVBYSEInf8vqNAfW0
job_GOnSGHWLvv2OXvYX49bYlQMz5JY
job_y934C_owXDCK1hOWl2YqcrGX38Y
job_AQjI-z_e-1pmNUQRjqegs-oUPAo
job_Q-kePLXcwAuGLLF5XQoaPZt6cVM
job_mm3rq7n4fc3wNGzEcP9agnq7KUw
job_AD5lwGbbwErLorbELhnN5MDVyW0
job_JWAg0WeLrHi0TCUWKPqCa5UD8xY
job_2xr6hAVwikbODpKKlkl19MNRpvw
job_gzStGMYj3ezVe5ASfOmIce5CCZY
job_mv3KkXU3MtaXU2IGjDsQFZ8CoP0

Answer (score 0):

You may be hitting job load rate limits. For example, if you try to start more than two load jobs per minute for the same table, the load jobs against that table will be defferred, while other load jobs against other tables may continue at normal speed.

There are per-project limits on rate at which load jobs will be started and limits on the number of load jobs that can be running per project at any one time. If you send jobs faster than this, we'll queue, but as you've noticed, our queueing is not a fair queue, and can start newer jobs before older ones.

Aborting pending jobs is a commonly requested feature. If you file a feature request [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/) that will help us prioritize it.

Comment: Thanks, I filed a feature request here: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=97